# Is it possible to type text from a specific cursor location?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

Given -> Selenium version 1 and 
Form Field Type -> Textbox.

What I am trying to do is this ->
Type string M1 and then send carriage return and then type string M2 into the textbox area.

Answer (score 2):

If `driver` is your web driver instance here is how the code in python look like, `switch_to.active_element` is what you need to take your `send_key` inputs for the element under the cursor (assuming you are familiar with the more common way of finding by a selector or xpath or id and then using `send_to` for that)

```
active_ele = driver.switch_to.active_element
active_ele.send_keys("bla bla message")
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

In Selenium there is a call from Actions(driver).SendKeys where you can can send keys without specifying an element. Use this to SendKeys to your Textbox element and then a separate call to just send a Selenium.Enter character.

EG. In C#, where _myDriver is your WebDriver.

```
(new Actions(_myDriver)).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter).Perform();
```

Alternatively, if you are on a windows machine you can use [Windows Send Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) and send a Enter keystroke then.